# Joining two data frames with left_join()

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, left-join, tidyr

I am trying to two data frames (`df_a` and `df_b`) in R (essentially I want to repopulate `df_a` with the updated data contained within `df_b`). The columns in `df_b` are all present in `df_a`. Within `df_b` there is (important) redundancy in `ref_transcript_name`, `ref_transcript_id`, and `ref_gene_name`, but all values of `qry_transcript_id` are unique and have a one-to-one relationship with `df_a`. My assumption here is that a `left_join()` would do the trick. I've tried:

1. `df_c <- left_join(df_a, df_b)` - here `df_c` is identical to `df_b`
2. `df_c <- left_join(df_a, df_b, by = "qry_transcript_id")` - here `df_c` contains the three non-guide columns of `df_b` as new columns of `df_c`.

I'm clearly missing something fundamental about the join functions here, but essentially I want to populate (most of) the missing values in `df_a` with the values from `df_b`.

Here are my data:

```
dput(df_a)
structure(list(ref_gene_id = c("LOC108906895", NA, NA, "LOC108906894", 
"LOC108906894", "LOC108906894", "LOC108906889", "LOC108906897", 
"LOC108906897", NA, "LOC108906891", "LOC108906890", "LOC108906896", 
NA, "LOC108906893", NA, "LOC108906892", "LOC108905349", "LOC108905349", 
"LOC108905349", "LOC108905394", "LOC108905394", "LOC108905439", 
"LOC108905439", "LOC108905439", "LOC108905439", "LOC108905439", 
"LOC108905439", "LOC108905439", "LOC108905439", "LOC108905439", 
"LOC108905439", "LOC108905439", "LOC108905439", "LOC108905350", 
"LOC108905395", "LOC108905377", "LOC108905377", "LOC108905399", 
"LOC108905399", "LOC108905452", "LOC108905450", "LOC108905450", 
"LOC108905450", "LOC108905425", "LOC108905427", "LOC108905429", 
"LOC108905426", "LOC108905352", "LOC108905375", "LOC108905391", 
NA, NA, NA), qry_gene_id = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 22L, 24L, 
27L, 25L, 26L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L), .Label = c("G229", "G230", 
"G232", "G233", "G234", "G235", "G236", "G237", "G238", "G239", 
"G240", "G241", "G242", "G243", "G244", "G245", "G246", "G247", 
"G248", "G249", "G250", "G251", "G252", "G253", "G254", "G255", 
"G256", "G257", "G258", "G259", "G260", "G261"), class = "factor"), 
    ref_gene_name = c("uncharacterized LOC108906895", NA, NA, 
    "uncharacterized LOC108906894", "uncharacterized LOC108906894", 
    "uncharacterized LOC108906894", "myosin regulatory light chain sqh", 
    "sushi, von Willebrand factor type A, EGF and pentraxin domain-containing protein 1", 
    "sushi, von Willebrand factor type A, EGF and pentraxin domain-containing protein 1", 
    NA, "uncharacterized LOC108906891", "protein twisted gastrulation", 
    "paraplegin", NA, "fork head domain-containing protein crocodile", 
    NA, "forkhead box protein F1-like", "centrosomal protein of 135 kDa-like", 
    "centrosomal protein of 135 kDa-like", "centrosomal protein of 135 kDa-like", 
    "nuclear transcription factor Y subunit alpha", "nuclear transcription factor Y subunit alpha", 
    "homeodomain-interacting protein kinase 2", "homeodomain-interacting protein kinase 2", 
    "homeodomain-interacting protein kinase 2", "homeodomain-interacting protein kinase 2", 
    "homeodomain-interacting protein kinase 2", "homeodomain-interacting protein kinase 2", 
    "homeodomain-interacting protein kinase 2", "homeodomain-interacting protein kinase 2", 
    "homeodomain-interacting protein kinase 2", "homeodomain-interacting protein kinase 2", 
    "homeodomain-interacting protein kinase 2", "homeodomain-interacting protein kinase 2", 
    "myb-like protein X", "uncharacterized LOC108905395", "uncharacterized LOC108905377", 
    "uncharacterized LOC108905377", "uncharacterized LOC108905399", 
    "uncharacterized LOC108905399", "uncharacterized LOC108905452", 
    "uncharacterized LOC108905450", "uncharacterized LOC108905450", 
    "uncharacterized LOC108905450", "uncharacterized LOC108905425", 
    "N-alpha-acetyltransferase 38, NatC auxiliary subunit", "cytochrome c oxidase assembly factor 6 homolog", 
    "N-alpha-acetyltransferase 30A", "ESF1 homolog", "atypical kinase COQ8B, mitochondrial", 
    "calphotin-like", NA, NA, NA), gene_annotation = c("refseq", 
    "novel", "novel", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", 
    "refseq", "refseq", "novel", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", 
    "novel", "refseq", "novel", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", 
    "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", 
    "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", 
    "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", 
    "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", 
    "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", 
    "refseq", "refseq", "novel", "novel", "novel"), ref_transcript_id = c("XR_001964310.2", 
    NA, NA, "XR_001964308.1", "XR_001964308.1", "XR_001964308.1", 
    "XM_018710327.1", "XM_018710334.2", "XM_018710334.2", NA, 
    "XM_018710330.2", "XM_018710328.1", "XM_018710333.1", NA, 
    "XM_018710332.1", NA, "XM_018710331.1", "XM_018708179.2", 
    "XM_018708179.2", "XM_018708179.2", "XM_018708228.2", "XM_018708229.2", 
    "XM_018708292.1", "XM_018708292.1", "XM_023457437.1", "XM_018708292.1", 
    "XM_018708292.1", "XM_018708292.1", "XM_018708292.1", "XM_018708292.1", 
    "XM_018708299.1", "XM_018708292.1", "XM_018708292.1", "XM_018708292.1", 
    "XM_018708180.1", "XM_018708231.1", "XM_018708208.2", "XM_023453940.1", 
    "XM_018708235.2", "XM_018708235.2", "XM_018708321.1", "XM_018708319.1", 
    "XM_018708318.1", "XM_018708318.1", "XM_018708263.1", "XM_018708266.1", 
    "XM_018708267.1", "XM_018708265.1", "XM_018708181.2", "XM_018708205.1", 
    "XM_018708226.1", NA, NA, NA), qry_transcript_id = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
    28L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 27L, 31L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
    39L, 40L, 41L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 42L, 46L, 49L, 47L, 48L, 50L, 
    51L, 52L, 53L, 54L), .Label = c("TU429", "TU430", "TU431", 
    "TU435", "TU436", "TU437", "TU438", "TU439", "TU440", "TU441", 
    "TU442", "TU443", "TU444", "TU445", "TU446", "TU447", "TU448", 
    "TU449", "TU450", "TU451", "TU452", "TU453", "TU454", "TU455", 
    "TU456", "TU457", "TU458", "TU459", "TU460", "TU461", "TU462", 
    "TU463", "TU464", "TU465", "TU466", "TU467", "TU468", "TU469", 
    "TU470", "TU471", "TU472", "TU473", "TU474", "TU475", "TU476", 
    "TU477", "TU478", "TU479", "TU480", "TU481", "TU482", "TU483", 
    "TU484", "TU485"), class = "factor"), ref_transcript_name = structure(c(30L, 
    NA, NA, 29L, 29L, 29L, 12L, 19L, 19L, NA, 28L, 18L, 17L, 
    NA, 6L, NA, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 15L, 16L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 11L, 22L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 23L, 
    27L, 26L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 14L, 4L, 13L, 5L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, 
    NA), .Label = c("atypical kinase COQ8B, mitochondrial", "calphotin-like", 
    "centrosomal protein of 135 kDa-like", "cytochrome c oxidase assembly factor 6 homolog, transcript variant X1", 
    "ESF1 homolog", "fork head domain-containing protein crocodile", 
    "forkhead box protein F1-like", "homeodomain-interacting protein kinase 2, transcript variant X1", 
    "homeodomain-interacting protein kinase 2, transcript variant X11", 
    "homeodomain-interacting protein kinase 2, transcript variant X8", 
    "myb-like protein X", "myosin regulatory light chain sqh", 
    "N-alpha-acetyltransferase 30A", "N-alpha-acetyltransferase 38, NatC auxiliary subunit", 
    "nuclear transcription factor Y subunit alpha, transcript variant X1", 
    "nuclear transcription factor Y subunit alpha, transcript variant X2", 
    "paraplegin", "protein twisted gastrulation", "sushi, von Willebrand factor type A, EGF and pentraxin domain-containing protein 1", 
    "uncharacterized LOC108905377, transcript variant X1", "uncharacterized LOC108905377, transcript variant X2", 
    "uncharacterized LOC108905395", "uncharacterized LOC108905399", 
    "uncharacterized LOC108905425, transcript variant X1", "uncharacterized LOC108905450, transcript variant X1", 
    "uncharacterized LOC108905450, transcript variant X2", "uncharacterized LOC108905452, transcript variant X2", 
    "uncharacterized LOC108906891", "uncharacterized LOC108906894", 
    "uncharacterized LOC108906895, transcript variant X2"), class = "factor"), 
    transcript_annotation = c("refseq", "novel", "novel", "refseq", 
    "refseq", "novel", "refseq", "refseq", "novel", "novel", 
    "novel", "novel", "refseq", "novel", "refseq", "novel", "refseq", 
    "refseq", "novel", "novel", "refseq", "refseq", "novel", 
    "novel", "refseq", "novel", "novel", "novel", "novel", "novel", 
    "refseq", "novel", "novel", "novel", "refseq", "refseq", 
    "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "novel", "refseq", "refseq", 
    "refseq", "novel", "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "novel", 
    "refseq", "refseq", "refseq", "novel", "novel", "novel"), 
    class_code = structure(c(1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L), .Label = c("=", "c", "j", "k", "u"), class = "factor")), row.names = 432:485, class = "data.frame")
```

```
dput(df_b)
structure(list(qry_transcript_id = structure(1:10, .Label = c("TU118", 
"TU151", "TU255", "TU417", "TU430", "TU431", "TU485", "TU543", 
"TU687", "TU807"), class = "factor"), ref_transcript_name = structure(c(8L, 
1L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 4L, NA, 5L, 6L, 3L), .Label = c("apoptosis-stimulating of p53 protein 1 isoform X3", 
"basic proline-rich protein-like", "microtubule-associated protein 10-like", 
"protein dopey homolog PFC0245c-like", "protein sprint isoform X2", 
"serine/arginine repetitive matrix protein 2-like", "tigger transposable element-derived protein 1-like", 
"uncharacterized protein LOC108904829"), class = "factor"), ref_transcript_id = c("XP_018563024", 
"XP_023014054", "XP_019880584", "XP_018578361", "XP_024947529", 
"XP_024947524", NA, "XP_030753146", "XP_018575004", "XP_023028347"
), ref_gene_name = c("* uncharacterized protein LOC108904829", 
"* apoptosis-stimulating of p53 protein 1 ", "* basic proline-rich protein-like", 
"* tigger transposable element-derived protein 1-like", "* protein dopey homolog PFC0245c-like", 
"* protein dopey homolog PFC0245c-like", NA, "* protein sprint ", 
"* serine/arginine repetitive matrix protein 2-like", "* microtubule-associated protein 10-like"
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Hopefully my subsetting doesn't create problems here, but in the full data set, all `qry_transcript_ids` in `df_b` are contained with `df_a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mutate` and `coalesce` along with `left_join` to achieve your merge requirement. Try the following example.

```
 x <- data.frame(Id  = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "E"),
                 X1  = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, NA),
                 XY  = c("x2", "x4", "x6", "x8", NA),
                 XZ  = c("x2", NA, NA, "x8", "x10"))
 
 y <- data.frame(Id  = c("A", "B", "B", "D", "E"),
                 Y1  = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L),
                 XY  = c("y1", "y3", "y5", "y7", "y9"),
                 XZ  = c("y1", "y3", "y5", "y7", "y9"))
 
aa <- x %>% left_join(y, by="Id") %>% 
            mutate(XY = coalesce(XY.x,XY.y)) %>% 
            mutate(XZ = coalesce(XZ.x,XZ.y)) %>% select(Id, X1, XY, XZ)

> aa 
  Id X1 XY   XZ
1  A  1 x2   x2
2  B  3 x4   y3
3  B  3 x4   y5
4  C  5 x6 <NA>
5  C  7 x8   x8
6  E NA y9  x10
```

Answer (score 1):

left_join keeps all of the data in the first data frame. Essentially, it will do nothing if the columns in df_b are all within df_a, as in the first case you have shown:

```
df_c <- left_join(df_a, df_b)
```

On the other hand, in the second example the join is on "qry_transcript_id". In this case the columns other than "qry_transcript_id" are treated as distinct from those in df_a. Hence the ".y" added to them.

```
df_c <- left_join(df_a, df_b, by = "qry_transcript_id")
```

It sounds like what you want is probably inner_join.

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks for clearing up my confusion with ```left_join()```. Doesn't ```inner_join()``` just return a df with rows from ```df_a``` that match ```df_b```? Essentially, I want to repopulate ```df_a``` with the values of ```df_b``` but retain the rest of the data within ```df_a```. My original post might not have been so clear in that regard.